# Can i use the version number less than the last?

Tags: app-store-connect

Can I use the version number less than the last approved version by apple?
**for Example:**

Current version on app store :`1.8.0`
New version I want to use : `1.0`

**Is it possible?**

Can i also change the App name showing on iTunes store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lowering application version:** Lowering the version number of an iOS application is not possible once your application has been approved. You can only go up: from `1.8.0` to `1.8.0.1` for example.

**Changing application name:** Changing the application name is possible when you create a new version of the application. You cannot modify the name of the current version. The new application name needs to be available for the chosen language.

Good luck!

Comment: Now we can change the version number on apple developer portal.